# gitlab ci bash script variable modification

Tags: bash, sed, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In GitLab CI script I wanted to

1. Remove any character other then numbers and dot (.) and
2. remove all the text after 2nd dot [Ex 5.6.7.8 -> 5.6] if dot exists in text.

So for that I have tried to use sed , but it's not working in GitLab Script (working on bash shell locally)

```
export BRANCH_NAME={$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'
```

any idea what is missing here ?

If sed is not going to work here then any other option to achieve the same?

Edit :
As per @WiktorStribiżew
- echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | sed 's/.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'
- export BRANCH_NAME=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed 's/.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'

echo is working but export is not

Comment: Does `echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g'` work? Also, you probably meant `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`, not `{$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`

Comment: I go with @WiktorStribiżew - i can also clarify that there is no reason sed should not work in gitlab pipelines (unless it is not installed on the underlying system)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g' is working but 
-export BRANCH_NAME=${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME} | sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'  | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g' 
is not working !!!

Comment: Yeah, just wrap with `$(...)`. See my full answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to remove all text after and including second dot you need

```sh
sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\).*/\1/'
```

The `sed 's/\.[^.]*$//'` sed command removes the *last* dot and any text after it.

Next, you must have made a typo and you actually meant to write `${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}` and not `{$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}`.

So, you might be better off with

```sh
export BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" | sed 's/\([^.]*\.[^.]*\).*/\1/' | sed 's/[^0-9.]//g')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ export BRANCH_NAME=$(echo "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" |sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g;s/\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)\.[^ ]*/\1/g')
```

Comment: I think you used `sed 's/[A-Za-z]*//g` to remove `Ex`, right? I think it was just a shortened word "example", the string OP just wanted to share was `5.6.7.8`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Indeed.  Thanks for pointing that out.